# Usercontrol not retaining value

Tags: asp.net, webusercontrol

I have a usercontrol with a dropdown, a textbox and a search button in the master page. I select a value in the dropdown, fill in text in the textbox and click on the button. On button click it redirects to another page but all the values are reset. How can I get the value selected in the dropdown and the text in the redirected page?

Answer (score 0):

You need to post the values to the other page. You can for example pass the values in the url

```
redirectedUlr.aspx?value1=1&value2=2 etc...
```

Or you can store the value in the Session

```
Session["passedvalues"] = YourValues
```

Their is several way to handle this

Answer (score 0):

You can pass information between pages in various ways, some of which depend on how the redirection occurs. The following options are available even if the source page is in a different ASP.NET Web application from the target page, or if the source page is not an ASP.NET Web page:

- Use a query string.
- Get HTTP POST information from the source page.

The following options are available only when the source and target pages are in the same ASP.NET Web application.

- Use session state.
- Create public properties in the source page and access the property
  values in the target page.
- Get control information in the target page from controls in the
  source page.

For more information and examples, you can read the following article : 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw(v=vs.100).aspx